# Python al hacer append de un segundo objeto me modifica la lista de el primer objeto

Tags: python, lista, clase

no se si alguien me pueda ayudar al momento de llamar la clase me modifica la lista de mi primera instancia,quiero que se modifique en la segunda pero se mantenga en la primera

```
    class Test:
    # Fix below here
    def __init__(self, t_int=5, t_list=[]):
        self.t_int=t_int
        self.t_list=t_list


    # Fix above here

    def return_attributes(self):
        return self.t_int, self.t_list


test_1 = Test(1)
test_1.t_list.extend(["this", "should", "be", "here"])

test_2 = Test(2)
test_2.t_list.append("?")

#assert test_1.return_attributes() == (1, ["this", "should", "be", "here"])
#assert test_2.return_attributes() == (2, ["this", "should", "be", "here", "?"])
print(test_1.return_attributes())
print(test_2.return_attributes())
```

Comment: Buen día, si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

En `Python` las variables no son etiquetas que representan un valor, sino referencias a un objeto que contiene un valor, en otras palabras las variables en `Python` son referencias.

Por ejemplo si creamos una variable:

```
prueba = 9
```

Internamente la variable `prueba` crea un nuevo objeto de tipo entero (`int`) en la memoria y relaciona la referencia de ese objeto con la variable creada.

Si hacemos `print(prueba)` vamos a ver que el valor es `9` pero si queremos ver la referencia o dirección de la memoria podemos utilizar `id(prueba)` nos devolverá la dirección de la memoria donde existe el objeto `int` con el valor `9`.

Si creáramos una segunda variable:

```
otraPrueba = 9
```

Y si vemos el `id` de ambas variables vamos a ver que las dos apuntan a la misma dirección de memoria.

Ejemplo:

```
prueba = 9
otraPrueba = 9

print(id(prueba))
print(id(otraPrueba))
```

Esto devuelve:

```
2041136415216
2041136415216
```

### Aterrizando lo anterior a tu pregunta

Cuando creas tu lista `["this", "should", "be", "here"]` la estás asignando al atributo `self.t_list` de tu clase `Test` y cualquier instancia que crees va a tener la misma referencia y por eso se modifican los valores en todas las instancias.

Para evitarlo puedes utilizar `self.t_list = t_list.copy()` que como su nombre lo indica, crea una copia de los valores de la lista pero en un nuevo objeto, por lo que al modificar una instancia la otra no se afecta.

Ahora, en tu clase tu defines un argumento para inicializar la lista, puedes pasarle la lista de la primera instancia a la segunda para obtener los mismos valores que tenía la primera.

```
class Test:
    # Fix below here
    def __init__(self, t_int=5, t_list=[]):
        self.t_int = t_int
        self.t_list = t_list.copy()


    # Fix above here

    def return_attributes(self):
        return self.t_int, self.t_list


test_1 = Test(1)
test_1.t_list.extend(["this", "should", "be", "here"])

test_2 = Test(2, test_1.t_list)
test_2.t_list.append("?")

assert test_1.return_attributes() == (1, ["this", "should", "be", "here"])
assert test_2.return_attributes() == (2, ["this", "should", "be", "here", "?"])

print(test_1.return_attributes())
print(test_2.return_attributes())
```

Esto devuelve:

```
(1, ['this', 'should', 'be', 'here'])
(2, ['this', 'should', 'be', 'here', '?'])
```

Comment: Solo un detalle, en los nimero aparecen el mismo ID ya que python ya tiene "creados" algunos números (no recuerdo el rango). Si colocas número muy grandes verás que el ID es diferente aunque el valor ses el mismo.